# How do you make perspective layer formation?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to make a graphic that looks similar to the image below using "flat" or birdseye images. I'm not even sure of the right way to ask the question. Can someone please tell me what it is called and provide a few pointers?

[image: GIS stack]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just draw a series of diamond shapes with whatever you want in the shapes.

- Select the shapes
- Use the **Free Transform Tool** to reduce the height of all the shapes at once.
- Stack the shapes on top of each other
- Align the shapes
- Add your arrows.

[image]

If you want some added depth to the shapes, add bottom sides by copying the base shape and adding 2 anchors for the sides and align them vertically, then move it behind your base diamond shape.

[image]

I find the 3D effect a bit of overkill for stuff like this.

Comment: You could use [Scale Skew Rotate](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-isometric-illustrations-using-the-ssr-method--vector-1058) (so for you one skew more) for if you want a true isometric tough as its easy to automate.  This action should be in every designers toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So you'll make each of your graphics a symbol.

Draw a square. Select the square>Effects>3d rotate

Move the perspective box around till you have it how you want and then you can map the symbol art to your square.

If you want to change things, you can access the 3d effect through the appearance panel.

Play around, give it a shot!